# krige() function with SpatialPointsDataFrame in R

Tags: r, sp

I would like to make some kriging in a belgian territory.

I got a data set called `clean.donnees.Ni` after removing outliers and `NA`values.

I first tried simply with this, but got this warning as result :

```
Ni.krig <- krige(formula = Ni~1,
                 data = clean.donnees.Ni,
                 locations = ~x+y,
                 newdata = krig.grid, 
                 model = Ni.vg.fit)

Warnings : Covariance matrix singular at location [50686, 156893,0]: skipping
```

I found on other topics that I probably got points at the same location.
([R gstat krige() - Covariance matrix singular at location [5.88,47.4,0]: skipping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222192/r-gstat-krige-covariance-matrix-singular-at-location-5-88-47-4-0-skipping))

They advice to use this to remove points on the same location:

```
clean.donnees.Ni <- clean.donnees.Ni[-zerodist(clean.donnees.Ni)[,1],]
```

When I did this, I finally thought I could make krige() work, but instead it nows returns me this error :

```
Ni.krig <- krige(formula = Ni~1,
                 data = clean.donnees.Ni,
                 locations = ~x+y,
                 newdata = krig.grid, 
                 model = Ni.vg.fit)

Error in `coordinates<-`(`*tmp*`, value = locations) : 
  setting coordinates cannot be done on Spatial objects, where they have already been set
```

Because I had to transform `clean.donnees.Ni` in a SpatialPointsDataFrame, locations can't read ~x+y anymore.

Does anyone knows how to makes kriging work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is a spatial data object then you give it to the `locations` argument - you only do `locations = ~x+y` if you have a non-spatial data frame with coordinates in those columns. So I think:

```
coordinates(krig.grid) <- ~x+y

Ni.krig <- krige(formula = Ni~1,
                 locations = clean.donnees.Ni,
                 newdata = krig.grid, 
                 model = Ni.vg.fit)
```

will work for you.

I can reproduce your error with a test dataset, and make it work:

```
> d = data.frame(x=runif(100), y=runif(100), Z=rnorm(100))
> coordinates(d)=~x+y
> 
> k = krige(formula = Z~1, data=d, locations=~x+y, newdata=d)
Error in `coordinates<-`(`*tmp*`, value = locations) : 
  setting coordinates cannot be done on Spatial objects, where they have already been set
> 
> k = krige(formula = Z~1, locations=d, newdata=d)
[inverse distance weighted interpolation]
```

From the help:

```
locations: object of class ‘Spatial’ or ‘sf’, or (deprecated) formula
          defines the spatial data locations (coordinates) such as
          ‘~x+y’

    data: data frame: should contain the dependent variable,
          independent variables, and coordinates, should be missing if
          locations contains data.
```

Comment: I tried but now I get this as error: 

```Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'obj' in selecting a method for function 'coordinates': trying to get slot "bbox" from an object (class "data.table") that is not an S4 object
```
I don't really understand why it doesn't work :
```> typeof(clean.donnees.Ni)
[1] "S4"
```

Comment: Somewhere you've got a `data.table` object. `Krig.grid` perhaps if its not your data points. Edit your Q and show `summary` and/or `class` of your inputs.

Comment: Hi, you were right, my krig.grid had to be also an S4 object ! I still got troubles to plot this, because I've never worked with S4 object. Maybe you can help me ?

Comment: If you've got more problems, ask a new question, and give as much detail as possible on the data you are feeding the functions - show their `summary` or print them, or create sample data from things we can all use. Tag it "r" and "kriging" and I'll see it!